# onEdit Search for specific text and copy corresponding value

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

**The Problem**

I am attempting to use an onEdit trigger to copy values based on a "key" from one sheet to appropriate column/row on the next sheet.

A script that I found looks up the value and copies over. The only downside is it runs for each row even if the values were already filled in. However, I only want the script to run for the cell that is being edited. Here is a sample sheet.

[Here is a link to the sheet that I am working with.](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1u4JrvqG-LgeZSJsyGBmkvrNea9Go6-rQkarR-m9ffU8/edit?usp=sharing)

**Desired Outcome**

What I am looking to achieve is if I insert any value into Column B and it matches what appears on the Directory, then the row that was edited is updated to include values found on Directory. However, it should not affect any previously edited rows.

**The Script**

```
function updateEntrees() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  
  var sh1=ss.getSheetByName('Directory');
  var rg1a=sh1.getRange(2,1,sh1.getLastRow()-1,1); 
  var vA1a=rg1a.getValues();
  var rg1b=sh1.getRange(2,2,sh1.getLastRow()-1,5);  // Modified
  var vA1b=rg1b.getValues();

  var sh2=ss.getSheetByName('Insert');
  var rg2a=sh2.getRange(2,2,sh2.getLastRow()-1,1); 
  var vA2a=rg2a.getValues();
  var rg2b=sh2.getRange(2,3,sh2.getLastRow()-1,5);  // Modified
  var vA2b=rg2b.getValues();
  
  
  for(var i=0;i<vA1a.length;i++) {
    for(var j=0;j<vA2a.length;j++) {
      if(vA1a[i][0]==vA2a[j][0]) {
        vA2b[j]=vA1b[i];  // Modified
      }
    }
  }
  rg2b.setValues(vA2b);
}
```

*Example 1:*
If in A5 I input "Gary" then the script would look up "Gary" from the Directory sheet and copy over 'Black' and 'Tiger' to the appropriate row. (The script above currently does this...see example 2).

| Input Sheet | A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Bob | Orange | Dog |
| 2 | Carrie | Blue | Cat |
| 3 | Juan | Green | Cat |
| 4 | Stephanie | Red | Bird |
| 5 | Gary |  |  |

Here's the "Directory" sheet.

| Directory Sheet | A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Bob | Orange | Dog |
| 2 | Carrie | Blue | Cat |
| 3 | Juan | Green | Cat |
| 4 | Stephanie | Red | Bird |
| 5 | Gary | Black | Tiger |

*Example 2:*
If I manually change Stephanie's color to Green and the animal to Elephant, when I input "Gary" into the next row, Stephanie's color is reverted back to Red and animal to Bird. I want to only edit the values based on the row that is being edited. So if I type in "Gary" then only Gary's line is affected, not the rest of the lines.

| Input Sheet | A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Bob | Orange | Dog |
| 2 | Carrie | Blue | Cat |
| 3 | Juan | Green | Cat |
| 4 | Stephanie | Green | Elephant |
| 5 | Gary |  |  |

Answer (score 1):

In your situation, how about the following sample script?

#### Sample script:

```js
function onEdit(e) {
  const range = e.range;
  const sheet = range.getSheet();
  if (sheet.getSheetName() != "Insert" || range.columnStart != 2 || range.rowStart == 1 || range.isBlank()) return;
  const insertValues = sheet.getRange("B2:B" + sheet.getLastRow()).getValues();
  const directorySheet = e.source.getSheetByName("Directory");
  const obj = directorySheet.getRange("A2:D" + directorySheet.getLastRow()).getValues().reduce((o, [a, ...v]) => (o[a] = v, o), {});
  const values = insertValues.map(([b]) => obj[b] || Array(3).fill(null));
  sheet.getRange(2, 3, values.length, values[0].length).setValues(values);
}
```

- In this sample script, when the dropdown list of column "B" of "Insert" is changed, the values from "Directory" sheet are searched using the dropdown list value. And, those values are put to "Insert" sheet as the overwrite. By this, even when other cells in "Insert" sheet are changed, the changed cells are back using the values of "Directory" sheet.

#### Note:

- This script is run by the simple trigger of OnEdit. So when you directly run the script, an error occurs, because the event object `e` is not given. Please be careful about this.

#### Reference:

- [Simple Triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers)

Comment: Your point about "even when other cells in "Insert" sheet are changed, teh changed cells are back using the values of "Directory" sheet" is what I am attempting to avoid. The script works wonderfully from the perspective of having the value added. Where it misses is it should not overwrite what is existing on the "insert" sheet. Another example I will add is if I add someone who is not in "Directory" sheet to "Insert" sheet, it should not be overwritten. If I add, "James" and the color, animal, etc, but then choose someone from the dropdown, "James"  color and animal are removed.